# Simple subtraction of two square matrices giving strange results

Tags: matrix

I'm new to Mathematica, and I'm writing a function to calculate a complicated pdf. I'm having trouble doing something very basic, subtracting one square matrix from another. I've reduced my problem to a simple example shown below.

```
Test[s_, cm_] = Module[{a, b, c},
   a = s Transpose[s];
   b = cm + a;
   c = Transpose[s]*Inverse[b]*s;
   c
   ];
```

In this function, s is a 2x2 matrix and cm is a 2x2 covariance matrix. It works as expected, producing a 2x2 matrix as output:

```
Test[{{0.4, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.4}}, {{1, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}]

{{0.203956, -0.116044}, {-0.116044, 0.203956}}
```

The next step of my function is to subtract c from the 2x2 identity matrix. This works fine if I do it outside the function:

```
IdentityMatrix[2] - Test[{{0.4, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.4}}, {{1, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}]

{{0.796044, 0.116044}, {0.116044, 0.796044}}
```

However, when I do this subtraction in the function itself, I get something totally unexpected:

```
Test[s_, cm_] = Module[{a, b, c},
   a = s Transpose[s];
   b = cm + a;
   c = Transpose[s]*Inverse[b]*s;
   IdentityMatrix[2] - c
   ];

Test[{{0.4, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.4}}, {{1, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}]

{{{{0.796044, 1.11604}, {1.11604, 0.796044}}, {{-0.203956, 0.116044}, {0.116044, -0.203956}}}, 
{{{-0.203956, 0.116044}, {0.116044, -0.203956}}, {{0.796044, 1.11604}, {1.11604, 0.796044}}}}
```

I must be misunderstanding something very basic, I would really appreciate it if anybody can suggest where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `Test` with `SetDelayed` (:=)

```
Clear["Global`*"];    

Test[s_, cm_]:=
 Module[{a, b, c},
  a = s Transpose[s];
  b = cm + a;
  c = Transpose[s] * Inverse[b] * s;
  IdentityMatrix[2] - c]

Test[{{0.4, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.4}}, {{1, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}]
```

{{0.796044, 0.116044}, {0.116044, 0.796044}}

A **rule of thumb** for beginners:
Define functions with `SetDelayed` and assign values to variables with `Set` (=).

You can inspect `Test` with a `?` followed by it:

```
?Test
```

[image]

Inspect your definitions of `Test` with `Set` (=) and see what happens.

From the Documentation:

`SetDelayed` "assigns rhs to be the delayed value of lhs. rhs is maintained in an unevaluated form. When lhs appears, it is replaced by rhs, evaluated afresh each time."

Comment: Thanks eldo, that was it. I clearly have a lot to learn. I'm grateful for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE  and thanks for the accept.